# Can i show a Planner link inside SharePoint team site home page using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I have a power automate flow to do the following:-

1. When an item is created
2. Create a channel inside existing team
3. Create a Planner inside existing teams
4. Show the new plan as a tab inside the team channel

now i am unable to know if it is possible to add the new Plan inside the SharePoint site as well. i can do this using the UI as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1708877924934.png]

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1708877933441.png]

but can i do it using Power automate? or by calling graph api?

Thanks